# Ignoring absolute values for integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation with $\frac{dx}{dt}=1-x$ and $x=0$ when $t=0$.

The answer uses the result that $\int \frac{dx}{1-x}=\ln (1-x)$, hence getting the solution $x=1-e^{-t}$.

However I use $\int \frac{dx}{1-x}=\ln \left|1-x\right|$ instead, which gets me $x=1-e^{-t} \text{ or }1+e^{-t}$.

Am I right, or is it standard to not use the absolute signs?

Comment: $x=1$ is a constant solution of the equation. So maximal solutions cannot touch.

Comment: BTW In the integrations you are missing a minus sign

Comment: The 2nd "solution" isn't one as $1 + e^{-0} = 1 + 1 = 2 \ne 0$.

Comment: @Siminore. But doesn't there exist a concern that $x(t)$ may also take values above $1$, making $ln(1-x)$ undefined?

Comment: Your antiderivative is wrong.  It should say $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{1-x} = -\ln(1-x)$.  You neglected the chain rule by omitting the minus sign.

Comment: @ThomasE. It seems to me that you can solve your equation only in the connected region where the initial condition belongs. In this case $x(0)=0$, so that any maximal solution will stay below the line $x=1$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 1-x
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{1-x} = dt
$$
$$
-\ln|1-x| = t+\text{constant}
$$
$$
|1-x| = e^{-t}\cdot\text{positive constant}
$$
(Since $e$ to a real power is always positive.)
$$
1-x=e^{-t}\cdot\text{constant}
$$
$$
x = 1 - e^{-t}\cdot\text{constant}
$$
Since we want $x=0$ when $t=0$, the "constant" is $1$.

If you had wanted $x$ to be $2$ when $t=0$, then you'd have been in trouble if you'd neglected the absolute value.

All of this works if $x\ne 1$.  But you can check that $x=1$ for all values of $t$ is also a solution.

Comment: Good. But the absolute value is indeed useless, since $x(0)=0$ and $x(t) < 1$ by the local uniqueness theorem. Anyway, your solution is standard and works for every initial condition.